# Cant work out the jQuery find to locate object in hierarchy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Should be simple but I can't work it out.

I've got a page with a table, within that table is an autocomplete and a button, I want to locate the autocomplete when I click the button and make it disabled or enabled.  The disable/enabled part isn't the problem, I can't get it to traverse the heirarchy to find the autocomplete in the first place.  Here's the chunk of html I've got: -

```
<td colspan="3">
                    <fieldset class="buttons">
                    <div>
  <input class='required' style='width:400px' type='text' id='autoLook[0]' name='autoLook[0].id' value='' title='' />
  <div class='searchcontainer yui-skin-sam' id='abb890644f19d382ef69951344848d878'></div>
  <script type='text/javascript'>   var autoCompleteDataSource = new YAHOO.util.XHRDataSource("/FARTFramework/form/searchAJAX");
    autoCompleteDataSource.responseType = YAHOO.util.XHRDataSource.TYPE_XML;
    autoCompleteDataSource.responseSchema = {
 resultNode : "result", 
 fields : [
 { key: "name" }, 
 { key: "id" }
]
};
;
    autoComplete = new YAHOO.widget.AutoComplete('autoLook[0]','abb890644f19d382ef69951344848d878', autoCompleteDataSource);
    autoComplete.queryDelay = 0;
    autoComplete.prehighlightClassName = 'yui-ac-prehighlight';
    autoComplete.useShadow = false;
    autoComplete.minQueryLength = 3;
    autoComplete.typeAhead = false;
    autoComplete.forceSelection = true;
    autoComplete.maxResultsDisplayed = 20;
    autoComplete.shadow = false;
    var itemSelectHandler = function(sType, args) {
        var autoCompleteInstance = args[0];
        var selectedItem = args[1];
        var data = args[2];
        var id = data[1];
        updateHiddenInput(id, 0, 'forms')   };
    autoComplete.itemSelectEvent.subscribe(itemSelectHandler);
</script>
</div>

                        <input type="button" id="EnableDisable" value="Edit" onclick="enabledisable($(this))" />

                        <input type="hidden" class="required" id="forms[0]" name="forms[0].id" value="" />          
                        <input type="hidden" class="required" id="oldvalue[0]" name="oldvalue[0].id" value="" />
                        <input type="button" value="Remove Form" onclick="globalRemoveRow($(this),'forms')" />
                        <input type="button" value="Insert New Form Above" onclick="addRowWithin('/FARTFramework/testScenario/ajaxNewFormFragment',$(this))" />
                        <input type="button" value="Go to Form Definition" onclick="gotoNew('/FARTFramework/form/edit/',$(this))" />    
                    </fieldset>
                    <div id="hideDIV">
                        <table name="formSubTable[0]" id="formSubTable[0]">
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
```

The button I'm clicking is called "EnableDisable" and in the javascript I can do this: -

```
function enabledisable(theButton){
    $thebutton = $(theButton)
    $theInput = $thebutton.closest('td')
    var myValue = $theInput.html();
    alert(myValue)  
}
```

Which returns this: -

```
<fieldset class="buttons">
                    <div class="yui-ac">
  <input required="required" autocomplete="off" class="required yui-ac-input" style="width:400px" id="autoLook[0]" name="autoLook[0].id" value="" title="" type="text">
  <div class="searchcontainer yui-skin-sam yui-ac-container" id="af745a9597adf2dd98aeab126bc31bcb9"><div style="display: none;" class="yui-ac-content"><div style="display: none;" class="yui-ac-hd"></div><div class="yui-ac-bd"><ul><li style="display: none;"></li><li style="display: none;"></li><li style="display: none;"></li><li style="display: none;"></li><li style="display: none;"></li><li style="display: none;"></li><li style="display: none;"></li><li style="display: none;"></li><li style="display: none;"></li><li style="display: none;"></li></ul></div><div style="display: none;" class="yui-ac-ft"></div></div></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">   var autoCompleteDataSource = new YAHOO.util.XHRDataSource("/FARTFramework/form/searchAJAX");
    autoCompleteDataSource.responseType = YAHOO.util.XHRDataSource.TYPE_XML;
    autoCompleteDataSource.responseSchema = {
 resultNode : "result", 
 fields : [
 { key: "name" }, 
 { key: "id" }
]
};
```

I can see the input I want is the third line down, the first input there is in that html.  But when I try to expand the jquery to `$thebutton.closest('td').children('input').eq(0)` I get `undefined` returned.

I've tried all manner of first, next etc but no luck.  I know that the input will have the text autolook[xx] in it but there will be loads with that id and I can't tell what the number will be to just look for a specific id or name so need to traverse the html to find it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$thebutton.closest('td').find('input[type='text'])
```

Or

```
$thebutton.closest('td').find('input')
```

Or

```
$thebutton.closest('td').find('input:first')
```

Comment: Works great using find('input:first') thanks.  I can't believe I didn't try this, I'm sure I had!!! :S

Answer (score 1):

try tho change this:

```
function enabledisable(theButton){
    $thebutton = $(theButton)
    $theInput = $thebutton.closest('td')
    var myValue = $theInput.html();
    alert(myValue)  
}
```

to this:

```
$('#EnableDisable').click(function(){
    var myValue = $(this).closest('td').find('input').val();
    alert(myValue)  
});
```

and your html changed:

```
<input type="button" id="EnableDisable" value="Edit"  />
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this does work but is a bit of a re-write to how I was doing it (I have more than one page that uses this function so wanted to keep it in the js I'd written it in.  To this extent Dhaval's solution is closer to what I needed, but not by much.  If I could vote for both I would! :)

Comment: Glad to help you, I have showed another way to do it! good luck :) @MorkPork